# Datatables Dynamic URL from button click

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am new to JavaScript and although I find many questions regarding this topic..I think I need a bit more complete example/explanation.

Using ASP.NET Core and Datatables in a separate js file.
The Datatable loads fine, but now I've added a couple of buttons to my View and on Click I would like to apply a filter to the data. In my AP CALL in Controller I have a SWITCH statement to catch the filter parameter and return the filtered JSON.

View:

```
<input id="btnOpen" type="submit" value="Open" />
                            <input id="btnTraded" type="submit" value="Traded" />
                            <input id="btnClosed" type="submit" value="Closed" />
                            <input id="btnAll" type="submit" value="All" />
```

Controller:

```
#region API CALLS
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAll(string filter)
    {            
        switch (filter)
        {
            case "Traded":
...
```

JS: I have .onClick for each Button (sure there is a better way)

```
(function () {
$("#btnOpen").click(function () {
    dataTable.ajax.url("/Customer/Invoice/GetAll?filter=Open").load;
});});
(function () {
$("#btnTraded").click(function () {
    dataTable.ajax.url("/Customer/Invoice/GetAll?filter=Traded").load;
});
```

});

JS: For table

```
function loadDataTable() {
dataTable = $('#datatables-reponsive').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "ajax": {
        
        "url": "/Customer/Invoice/GetAll",  
    },
    "columnDefs": [{......
```

The onClicks reloads the table but the original data without the filter being passed to the API Call.

---

UPDATE:
The problem was that I should call OnLoad() as a function.
There was also some problem with the button OnClick function which never fired although the page did refresh. So I changed it as follows:
View:

```
 <input onclick="filter('open');" value="Open" />
```

JS:

```
function filter(data) {
if (data == "traded") {
    dataTable.ajax.url("/Customer/Invoice/GetAll?filter=Traded").load();
}
else if (data == "open") {
    dataTable.ajax.url("/Customer/Invoice/GetAll?filter=Open").load();
}
else if .......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I think the problem is that when you reload your data and resend it to `DataTable`, you're not loading them again in `ajax` block. My solution is first change the way that you fire datatable ajax :

```
(function () {
$("#btnOpen").click(function () {
    dataTable.ajax.url("/Customer/Invoice/GetAll?filter=Open").load();
});});
(function () {
$("#btnTraded").click(function () {
    dataTable.ajax.url("/Customer/Invoice/GetAll?filter=Traded").load();
});
```

related to [ajax url](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url()) `load()` should call as a function. Then:

```
dataTable = $('#datatables-reponsive').DataTable({
responsive: true,
"ajax": {
    
    "url": "/Customer/Invoice/GetAll",  
    "method" : "GET",
    "data" : function (data) {
                delete data.columns;
            }
},
"columnDefs": [{......
```

`"data"` function will destroy columns of your `DataTable` and load them again.

Comment: I realized that although the page is reloading, the button's OnClick event did not fire. I think it reloads due to the button type="Submit". So I changed the button to <input type="button" onclick="filterTraded()" value="Test"/> and added function function filterTraded() {
    dataTable.ajax.url("/Customer/Invoice/GetAll?filter=Traded").load;
}. This function now fires and page does refresh...but it does so without LoadDataTable function ever being called

Comment: Did you add `"data"` to your `"ajax"` block?

Comment: Yes, I did add the "data" to the "ajax" block

Comment: Another solution is about how you load the ajax of `dataTable`.I will update answer and check new solution and give me some response.

Comment: Thank you very much! You won't believe how much time I've spend on such a small thing. Also some problem with the button ... but I'll do post of end product